# using priority queue in c++ how to arrange elements in increasing order

Tags: c++, queue

```
typedef vector<vector<int> > board;
typedef pair<board,char> vec; 
priority_queue<pair<int,vec> > q;
```

how to arrange in asending order depending on the int value?

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the template argument also for the compare function: in other words, you should state how two pairs of <int, vec> should be compared.
Check the documentation [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)
At the moment you are using the std:less of pair, it does what stated [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp)

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in what you currently have should stop a basic priority queue of `pair<int,vec>`. However, that queue will order in descending priority (e.g. highest comes first) by using `std::less<T>` as the priority determinate.

If you want *ascending* priority (e.g. lower values are higher-priority), you need to reverse the comparator. I.e. `std::greater<T>`. An example appears below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

typedef std::vector<std::vector<int> > board;
typedef std::pair<board,char> vec; 
typedef std::pair<int,vec> elem;
std::priority_queue<elem, std::deque<elem>, std::greater<elem>> q;

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 rng{ std::random_device{}() };
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> dist(1,100);

    // add ten random picks for pair int value
    for (int i=1; i<=10; ++i)
        q.push(std::make_pair(dist(rng), vec{}));

    while (!q.empty())
    {
        auto obj = std::move(q.top());
        q.pop();
        std::cout << obj.first << '\n';
    }

}
```

**Output** (varies, obviously)

```
3
4
14
23
40
46
49
53
58
73
```

Comment: Nice thing you provided an example code! As in my answer, I would also argue that he needs to reimplement the comparator: in fact, if the first element of two pairs is equal, the standard comparator would look at the `vec`, and this may be undesirable in the use case.